# clicking on the_tags() generated tags to show all tagged posts page

Tags: php, tags

I'm start using `the_tags()` function, I want to create a list of tags using the `#` symbol like the hashtags. I've never used this function, and I've noticed that it will create a link to an url that is pointing to a mysitw.com/tag/selected-tag/, but if I try to click on it, I will see the home page. 
Do I need to create a tag page template for this to work as I'm expecting? I want to display all the contents that are under the same tag on a styled page or list. 
How I can do this ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling plugins or looking at their settings? SEO plugins may disable tag archives, so that might be why you are seeing the homepage. You could also use a default theme like Twenty Twenty to check whether it is indeed your theme lacking a template or enforcing a redirect.

Comment: I've added the `tag.php` template to my theme, now works fine. As I understand, I need an `archive.php` template, but also tag will work and is the template that the url will point.